# jstree criar novo node não funciona

Tags: jquery, html, jstree

Pessoal estou usando o [jstree](https://www.jstree.com/) para criar uma árvore.

Estou tentando criar um novo node, mas não estou conseguindo.

O primeiro nível de node estará já carregado no html, então somente os próximos serão adicionados pelo js.
Segue um exemplo:

```js
$("#tree").jstree();

$("#tree").on("click",function(){
  var nodeSelecionado = jQuery("#tree").jstree("get_selected");
  console.log(nodeSelecionado[0]);
  jQuery("#tree").jstree('create_node', $("#"+nodeSelecionado[0]), "node novo", 'last');
  jQuery("#tree").jstree("open_node", $("#"+nodeSelecionado[0]));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.0.8/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.0.8/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="tree">
    <ul>
        <li class="jstree-closed">Node 1</li>
        <li class="jstree-closed">Node 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri que faltava uma simples configuração, encontrado de acordo com essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22823644/2518370).

```
$('#tree').jstree({
    'core': {
        'check_callback': true
    }
});
```